# Prove equivalence relation for a metric space.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

**Adjusted Axioms / Postulates for a metric space**. Let $D$ be a function defined for all $a$ and $b$ in the metric space $M$

I.    $D(a,a)=0 \, \forall a$

II. $D(a,b)\geq0$ [the only adjusted one, **CRUCIAL**]

III. $D(a,b)=D(b,a)$

IV. *The Triangle inequality*

---

Question: Define $A \sim B$ to mean that $D(a,b)=0$. Prove equivalence relation for $\sim. $

*How does one do it?*

---

My attempt:

a) $a \sim a\,$ mean that $D(a,a)=0$ which is true according to *axiom I*.

b) According to *axiom III* we have that $D(a,b)=D(b,a)$. Since $a \sim b$ mean that $D(a,b)=0$ that means that also $D(b,a)=0$ therefore $b \sim a$.

c) How to show transitivity, here is where I am stuck at the moment.

Comment: You may want to use triangle inequality

Comment: Using the triangle inequality, I get this far: $D(a,c) \leq D(a,b) + D(b,c)$. If $a \sim b$  and $b \sim c$ therefore $D(a,b)=0$ and $D(b,c)=0$. Thus we get, $D(a,c) \leq 0+0$ and since $D(x_1,x_2)\geq0$ according to *axiom II* we have that $0 \leq D(a,c)\leq 0$ and therefore $D(a,c)=0$ and $a \sim c$. Is this right?

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 1):

If $D(a,b)=D(b,c)=0$ then observe by triangle inequality that $D(c,a) \leq D(a,b) + D(b,c) = 0 \implies D(c,a) = 0.$